# No overload for 'DoSomethingInt' matches delegate 'DoSomethingDelegate<T>'

Tags: c#, .net

```
class DelegateTest<T> where T: // ....
{
    public DelegateTest(DoSomethingDelegate<T> action = null)
    {
        if (action != null)
            _doSomething = action;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            //_doSomething = DoSomethingInt; // fails
            //_doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)DoSomethingInt; // fails
            //_doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)((Delegate)DoSomethingInt); // fails
            _doSomething = (val) => DoSomethingInt((int)((object)val)); // too ugly
        else //  ...
    }

    public void DoSomethingVeryComplex(T val)
    {
        // ....
        _doSomething(val);
        // ....
    }

    DoSomethingDelegate<T> _doSomething;

    static void DoSomethingInt(int val)
    {
    }
}

delegate void DoSomethingDelegate<T>(T val);
```

So, the delegate and the method are compatible by the signature, but this assignment doesn't work for some obscure reasons and I'm totally out of ideas how to make it work. Any better ideas other than to create a shim function?
This question is **not** about how this code can be rewritten in other ways. It's only about how to make this assignment work, and if that's impossible - why.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244017/discussion-on-question-by-user626528-no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-de).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know `T`, you can cast `this` to the specific generic type (`DelegateTest<int>`). Once you have that reference, you can use it for type-safe and type-specific access to its methods, properties, and fields, even private ones.

```
class DelegateTest<T>
{
    public DelegateTest()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            var self = this as DelegateTest<int>; //Magic!!
            self._doSomething = DoSomethingInt;
        }
    }

    DoSomethingDelegate<T> _doSomething;

    public void InvokeDoSomething(T x) => _doSomething(x);

    static void DoSomethingInt(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello. The argument was {0}", val);
    }
}

delegate void DoSomethingDelegate<T>(T val);
```

Quick test:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var o = new DelegateTest<int>();
        o.InvokeDoSomething(1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello. The argument was 1
```

[Link to DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FVmuXe)

Answer (score 2):

You can cast and assign the delegate directly if you use `Action<T>` instead of your custom delegate.

```
class DelegateTest<T>
{
    public DelegateTest()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            _doSomething = (Action<T>)(object)DoSomethingInt;
        }
    }

    Action<T> _doSomething;

    public void InvokeDoSomething(T x) => _doSomething(x);

    static void DoSomethingInt(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world! The argument was {0}", val);
    }
}
```

Quick test:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var o = new DelegateTest<int>();
        o.InvokeDoSomething(1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world! The argument was 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3Xlgr)

Comment: Hm. Quite strange, but it really works.

Comment: This only works because of the same kind of casting that the OP called "too ugly". This isn't really a better answer than the OP already knew.

Comment: "You can cast and assign the delegate directly if you use Action<T> instead of your custom delegate." - you can equally use the custom delegate. There isn't anything special about `Action<T>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity (1) No, it's not the same, as it doesn't require a shim, and (2) No, it doesn't work with the custom delegate. Have you tried it? If you can get it to work please post your own answer.

Comment: @JohnWu - It works when you do this: `_doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)(Delegate)(DoSomethingDelegate<int>)DoSomethingInt;`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to John Wu's [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet/71908088#71908088), but works with the `DoSomethingDelegate<T>` as well:

```
static void Main()
{
    new DelegateTest<int>().InvokeDoSomething(1);
    new DelegateTest<string>().InvokeDoSomething("Hello");
}

delegate void DoSomethingDelegate<T>(T val);

class DelegateTest<T>
{
    public DelegateTest()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            _doSomething = new DoSomethingDelegate<T>((Action<T>)(object)DoSomethingInt);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            _doSomething = new DoSomethingDelegate<T>((Action<T>)(object)DoSomethingString);
        else throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    DoSomethingDelegate<T> _doSomething;

    public void InvokeDoSomething(T x) => _doSomething(x);

    void DoSomethingInt(int val) => Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingInt({val})");
    void DoSomethingString(string val) => Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingString({val})");
}
```

Output:

```
DoSomethingInt(1)
DoSomethingString(Hello)
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HzU91F).

---

**Alternative 1:** As mentioned by Enigmativity in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet/71908823#comment127068209_71907658), casting the `DoSomethingInt` to `DoSomethingDelegate<T>` can also be achieved like this:

```
public DelegateTest()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        _doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)(Delegate)(DoSomethingDelegate<int>)DoSomethingInt;
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        _doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)(Delegate)(DoSomethingDelegate<string>)DoSomethingString;
    else throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/22FuQw).

It also makes the invocation of the delegate faster by about 20% compared to my original suggestion, for a reason explained by Matthew Watson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71920613/why-one-delegate-is-faster-than-the-other/71921546#71921546). My original suggestion involves two method invocations instead of one.

---

**Alternative 2:** A variant of John Wu's [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet/71914790#71914790), using the `switch` statement instead of `if`+`as`:

```
public DelegateTest()
{
    switch (this)
    {
        case DelegateTest<int> self: self._doSomething = DoSomethingInt; break;
        case DelegateTest<string> self: self._doSomething = DoSomethingString; break;
        default: throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSP4QG).

This one is type safe. You can't assign accidentally the wrong method to the wrong type. Invoking the delegate is as fast as the previous Alternative 1.

Comment: This is the same kind of ugly casting as the OP's "too ugly" method. It hasn't improved the OP position.

Comment: I agree that it's not less ugly than the OP's original solution. It has the advantage though that in case of type mismatch you'll get the `InvalidCastException` earlier. You'll get it during the construction of the `DelegateTest<T>` instance, not when the `InvokeDoSomething` method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the assignment in the first place, is that you're in scope of `DelegateTest<T>` where `T` can be any type and you're asking the compiler to allow something of type `DoSomethingDelegate<int>` to be assigned to a `DoSomethingDelegate<T>`. That's fine if `T` is `int` at run-time, but the compiler doesn't know that. It's an illegal cast, despite the run-time check for the type.

The best you can do is make your code more resilient to coding errors. Here's variation on Theo's answer that makes the code more strongly-typed. It's probably the best you're going to get without going to reflection.

```
static void Main()
{
    new DelegateTest<int>().InvokeDoSomething(1);
    new DelegateTest<string>().InvokeDoSomething("Hello");
}

delegate void DoSomethingDelegate<T>(T val);

class DelegateTest<T>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _delegates = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    private void Register<K>(DoSomethingDelegate<K> @delegate)
    {
        _delegates[typeof(K)] = @delegate;
    }
    
    public DelegateTest()
    {
        this.Register<int>(DoSomethingInt);
        this.Register<string>(DoSomethingString);
        if (_delegates.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)_delegates[typeof(T)];
        }
        else throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    DoSomethingDelegate<T> _doSomething;

    public void InvokeDoSomething(T x) => _doSomething(x);

    void DoSomethingInt(int val) => Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingInt({val})");
    void DoSomethingString(string val) => Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingString({val})");
}
```

That outputs:

```
DoSomethingInt(1)
DoSomethingString(Hello)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you are adding two entries in the `_delegates` dictionary when an instance is constructed, then you read one of the entries, and then the dictionary will never be used again and will remain a dead weight for the whole lifetime of the instance. Each instance has its own dictionary. You might want to make it `static`, but then the instantiation of a `DelegateTest<T>` might become a non-thread-safe operation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, that would be a better refactoring.

Comment: The dictionary isn't useful here, only unnecessary work. Your variant with `_doSomething = (DoSomethingDelegate<T>)(Delegate)(DoSomethingDelegate<int>)DoSomethingInt;` is perfectly enough.

Comment: @user626528 - The dictionary provides a more strongly-typed way of keeping you safe when doing these casts. It also reduces the number of `if`s in your code dramatically.