# Why one delegate is faster than the other?

Tags: c#, performance, generics, delegates, .net-6.0

I am trying to understand the reason for the difference in performance between two delegates. It occurred while I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet) question. @Enigmativity [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet/71908823#comment127068209_71907658) an alternative way to type-cast, that resulted in a delegate with faster invocation. Here is a minimal version of that code:

```
delegate void MyAction<T>(T val);
static int Counter;

// My suggestion
static MyAction<T> GetAction1<T>()
    => new MyAction<T>((Action<T>)(object)ActionInt);

// Enigmativity's suggestion
static MyAction<T> GetAction2<T>()
    => (MyAction<T>)(Delegate)(MyAction<int>)ActionInt;

static void ActionInt(int val) { Counter++; }
```

There is a custom generic delegate-type `MyAction<T>`, that has identical signature with the built-in [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1). We want to instantiate this delegate from a generic `<T>` method, and we want to cast it internally to a type-specific `ActionInt` method. You can see my approach and Enigmativity's approach. It seems that in both cases the type casting occurs during the instantiation of the `MyAction<T>` delegate. Invoking the resulting delegates should not incur type-casting overhead. At least this is my theory. But when I am measuring the performance of the resulting delegates, Enigmativity's delegate is consistently around 20% faster than mine:

```
static void Test(string title, MyAction<int> action)
{
    Counter = 0;
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) action(i);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{title}, Counter: {Counter:#,0}, Duration: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:#,0} msec");
}

Test("GetAction1", GetAction1<int>());
Test("GetAction2", GetAction2<int>());
Test("GetAction1", GetAction1<int>());
Test("GetAction2", GetAction2<int>());
```

Output:

```
GetAction1, Counter: 100,000,000, Duration: 444 msec
GetAction2, Counter: 100,000,000, Duration: 374 msec
GetAction1, Counter: 100,000,000, Duration: 447 msec
GetAction2, Counter: 100,000,000, Duration: 371 msec
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nZ33Z3).

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Your version doesn't seem to work on sharplab.io, which I was going to use to inspect the IL. But I'm guessing that you are creating two delegates, one via an implicit cast, one explicitly.

Comment: Since you've already tested the generic argument type, does `(MyAction<int>)ActionInt as MyAction<T>` count as readable?

Comment: Also FYI, c#11 / .net 7 may cache some implicit delegates (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5835#issuecomment-1055790728).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman my intention here is to understand the performance difference between these two approaches. I am not searching for a more readable or for an even faster approach. If you find something better than those, it might be more relevant to post it as an answer to user626528's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907658/no-overload-for-dosomethingint-matches-delegate-dosomethingdelegatet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a decompiler, we can discover the following:

Implementation of `GetAction1<T>()`:

```
IL_0000: ldnull
IL_0001: ldftn        void ConsoleApp1.UnderTest::ActionInt(int32)
IL_0007: newobj       instance void class [System.Runtime]System.Action`1<int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_000c: castclass    class [System.Runtime]System.Action`1<!!0/*T*/>
IL_0011: ldftn        instance void class [System.Runtime]System.Action`1<!!0/*T*/>::Invoke(!0/*T*/)
IL_0017: newobj       instance void class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<!!0/*T*/>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_001c: ret
```

Implementation of `GetAction2<T>()`:

```
IL_0000: ldnull
IL_0001: ldftn        void ConsoleApp1.UnderTest::ActionInt(int32)
IL_0007: newobj       instance void class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_000c: castclass    class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<!!0/*T*/>
IL_0011: ret
```

You can see in the first case that it is actually creating two delegates, and chaining one to the other.

In the second case it is only creating one delegate.

I can't explain the exact reason for this, but I would think that it's because of the extra cast to `object` in `GetAction1`.

---

There appears to be an even faster implementation, namely:

```
 public static MyAction<T> GetAction3<T>()
      => x => ActionInt((int)(object)x);
```

This generates much longer IL code:

```
IL_0000: ldsfld       class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<!0/*T*/> class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/'<>c__4`1'<!!0/*T*/>::'<>9__4_0'
IL_0005: dup
IL_0006: brtrue.s     IL_0021
IL_0008: pop
IL_0009: ldsfld       class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/'<>c__4`1'<!0/*T*/> class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/'<>c__4`1'<!!0/*T*/>::'<>9'
IL_000e: ldftn        instance void class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/'<>c__4`1'<!!0/*T*/>::'<GetAction3>b__4_0'(!0/*T*/)
IL_0014: newobj       instance void class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<!!0/*T*/>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_0019: dup
IL_001a: stsfld       class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/MyAction`1<!0/*T*/> class ConsoleApp1.UnderTest/'<>c__4`1'<!!0/*T*/>::'<>9__4_0'
IL_001f: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0020: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0021: ret
```

And yet it is faster for both the call to `GetAction3()` and executing the action that it returns.

Here's the benchmark program I tested with:

```
using System;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<UnderTest>();
    }
}

public class UnderTest
{
    public delegate void MyAction<T>(T val);
    public static int counter;

    public static MyAction<T> GetAction1<T>()
        => new MyAction<T>((Action<T>)(object)ActionInt);

    // Enigmativity's suggestion
    public static MyAction<T> GetAction2<T>()
        => (MyAction<T>)(Delegate)(MyAction<int>)ActionInt;

    public static MyAction<T> GetAction3<T>()
        => x => ActionInt((int)(object)x);

    public static MyAction<int> Act1 = GetAction1<int>();
    public static MyAction<int> Act2 = GetAction2<int>();
    public static MyAction<int> Act3 = GetAction3<int>();

    static void ActionInt(int val) { counter++; }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Action1()
    {
        _ = GetAction1<int>();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Action2()
    {
        _ = GetAction2<int>();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Action3()
    {
        _ = GetAction3<int>();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunAction1()
    {
        Act1(0);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunAction2()
    {
        Act2(0);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunAction3()
    {
        Act3(0);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
|     Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|----------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
|    Action1 | 13.3355 ns | 0.1670 ns | 0.1480 ns |
|    Action2 |  6.9685 ns | 0.1313 ns | 0.1228 ns |
|    Action3 |  1.3437 ns | 0.0321 ns | 0.0285 ns |
| RunAction1 |  2.4100 ns | 0.0454 ns | 0.0425 ns |
| RunAction2 |  1.6493 ns | 0.0594 ns | 0.0527 ns |
| RunAction3 |  0.8347 ns | 0.0295 ns | 0.0276 ns |
```

Of course, none of the actions actually use the `int` passed to them, since they all just call `ActionInt()` which ignores its argument.

I suppose you could also implement it as:

```
public static MyAction<T> GetAction3<T>()
    => _ => ActionInt(0);
```

which might be even faster, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Thanks! It makes some sense actually, since I am explicitly creating something new, while   Enigmativity's approach isn't.

Comment: Matthew I measured the `=> x => ActionInt((int)(object)x);` suggestion, and it seems that it is around 20% slower than my already slow approach! [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T8kWka).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I suspect C# 10 / .NET 6.0 has some additional optimisations. You can see the results above (0.8347 for RunAction3 versus 2.4100 for RunAction1). I'm using Benchmark.Net with a .NET 6.0 build for the timings (and a RELEASE build, of course).

Comment: The dotnetfiddle.net [seems to run](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PaBfPa) currently in release mode too. In my own machine (.NET 6.0.0-rtm.21522.10) your argument-casting suggestion is indeed faster than Enigmativity's suggestion by about 15% (in release mode).

Comment: Two delegates, that's what I was expecting, but didn't have quick access to tooling to prove it. And your other example is faster because it's a non-capturing lambda, which is promoted to a static method, with a static variable to cache the delegate.